# Installing YAML for PHP in IIS

Tags: yaml, php-extension, iis-10

I am trying to install the YAML 1.2 extension to PHP 5.6 under IIS 10 (Windows 10). I am using http://pecl.php.net/package/yaml/1.2.0/windows to download the files.

I have downloaded the PHP 5.6 non-thread-safe DLL (x86 to match my version of PHP), copied `php_yaml.dll` to my extension directory, copied `yaml.dll` to `C:\Windows\System32` (which is reported as one of the paths in `phpinfo()`) and added `extension=php_yaml.dll` to my `php.ini`. I've verified with `phpinfo()` that the correct `php.ini` file is being loaded, and commenting out other extensions removes them from the output of `phpinfo()`.

However, YAML doesn't appear in the output of `phpinfo()` and the functions are not loaded. Running `php-cgi.exe -v` from the command line gives a warning:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\PHP\php_5_06_14\ext\php_yaml.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
```

The file exists at the location specified and the permissions appear to be correct. What else can I do to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the use of PECL as package manager is being in dropping.
Having to install extensions in a server makes things more complicated and it depends on the environment, permissions, etc.

I'm sure someone could help you solve that (I haven't work on windows in years, so I can't)

But, instead I suggest you another solution. Maybe you can opt for it, maybe you have to stick with the extension, but, in case you can actually look for other option, I suggest you to use another library.

https://github.com/symfony/yaml

And, you could use Composer to install your libraries, I suggest you take a look at it.

Again, it may be for you or not, but I think this would be a lot easier.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I put the path to my extension directory in the path environment variable. That fixed the issue for me.